# How to know the topic from trained data (or predict the topic of new data) using trained topic modelling using OCTIS?

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp, lda, topic-modeling

I've trained an LDA for topic modelling using OCTIS. But I don't know how to see the predicted topic for each data input or how to apply/predict my trained model to new data.

This is the code and the output of the trained model:

**Input:**

```
# Custom dataset
from octis.dataset.dataset import Dataset
dataset = Dataset()
dataset.load_custom_dataset_from_folder("/content/new")

# Create Model
model = LDA(num_topics=5, alpha=0.1)

# Train the model 
output = model.train_model(dataset)
```

**Output:**

```
>> output
{'topic-word-matrix': array([[0.00030817, 0.00646953, 0.00338882, ..., 0.00030812, 0.00030813,
         0.00030812],
        [0.00041419, 0.00248425, 0.0004141 , ..., 0.0004141 , 0.0004141 ,
         0.0004141 ],
        [0.0002584 , 0.00025837, 0.00025836, ..., 0.00025836, 0.00025836,
         0.00025836],
        [0.00044957, 0.0004495 , 0.00044949, ..., 0.00269659, 0.00269643,
         0.00269655],
        [0.00238244, 0.0003972 , 0.00039719, ..., 0.00039719, 0.00039719,
         0.00039719]], dtype=float32),
 'topics': [['vaksin',
   'sertifikat',
   'aplikasi',
   'pertama',
   'alhamdulillah',
   'pedulilindungi',
   'ada',
   'padahal',
   'terimakasih',
   'nik'],
  ['aplikasi',
   'vaksin',
   'sertifikat',
   'guna',
   'data',
   'udh',
   'bikin',
   'pake',
   'login',
   'nik'],
  ['aplikasi',
   'vaksin',
   'sertifikat',
   'ada',
   'tanggal',
   'tgl',
   'di',
   'belum',
   'coba',
   'sangat'],
  ['covid',
   'vaksin',
   'jadi',
   'hp',
   'ada',
   'aplikasi',
   'mau',
   'kalau',
   'sakit',
   'salah'],
  ['aplikasi',
   'bahasa',
   'lahir',
   'bisa',
   'nx',
   'sertifikat',
   'pakai',
   'di',
   'vaksin',
   'indonesia']],
 'topic-document-matrix': array([[0.06667246, 0.98769081, 0.00190489, 0.00165357, 0.98805857,
         0.00392223, 0.00210558, 0.00219824, 0.0029861 , 0.00170955,
         0.00215115, 0.00160036, 0.00210585, 0.00210572, 0.0030779 ,
         0.00289892, 0.00289916, 0.00307764, 0.00317504, 0.00307748,
         0.00183547, 0.10921329, 0.00160071, 0.98933005, 0.00219851,
         0.49730667, 0.98768848, 0.00194217, 0.00194207, 0.99120653,
         0.00160038, 0.00363727, 0.23678468, 0.98545253, 0.00168113,
         0.0016811 , 0.99349433, 0.00229977, 0.00339057, 0.98769081,
         0.00190489, 0.00165355, 0.98805857, 0.00392223, 0.00210558,
         0.00219824, 0.00298613, 0.00170955, 0.00215115, 0.00160037],
        [0.06667251, 0.00307732, 0.00190493, 0.99338686, 0.00298535,
         0.00392244, 0.00210581, 0.00219835, 0.00298549, 0.00170954,
         0.00215096, 0.00160031, 0.00210574, 0.00210569, 0.00307775,
         0.00289909, 0.0028996 , 0.00307763, 0.0031751 , 0.98769003,
         0.00183529, 0.88495934, 0.00160057, 0.00266775, 0.0021984 ,
         0.00224775, 0.00307769, 0.99223095, 0.99223143, 0.00219834,
         0.64113957, 0.98545176, 0.00219818, 0.00363676, 0.00168091,
         0.00168108, 0.00162644, 0.00229943, 0.00339064, 0.00307732,
         0.00190493, 0.99338692, 0.00298535, 0.00392238, 0.00210581,
         0.00219834, 0.00298549, 0.00170954, 0.00215096, 0.00160031],
        [0.06667244, 0.00307741, 0.00190496, 0.0016533 , 0.00298539,
         0.98431122, 0.99157733, 0.99120724, 0.9880569 , 0.00170964,
         0.00215104, 0.99359852, 0.002106  , 0.99157727, 0.00307766,
         0.00289921, 0.9884032 , 0.0681117 , 0.98729986, 0.00307752,
         0.00183526, 0.0019427 , 0.0016006 , 0.00266733, 0.06295873,
         0.49595022, 0.00307819, 0.00194241, 0.00194218, 0.00219866,
         0.35405946, 0.00363706, 0.75662065, 0.00363694, 0.00168095,
         0.99327528, 0.00162655, 0.00229944, 0.00339072, 0.00307741,
         0.00190496, 0.0016533 , 0.00298541, 0.98431122, 0.99157733,
         0.99120724, 0.9880569 , 0.00170964, 0.00215105, 0.99359864],
        [0.06667253, 0.00307718, 0.00190488, 0.00165313, 0.00298533,
         0.00392208, 0.00210552, 0.00219805, 0.00298561, 0.99316174,
         0.00215088, 0.00160023, 0.00210566, 0.00210558, 0.98768842,
         0.9884038 , 0.00289898, 0.00307778, 0.00317501, 0.00307729,
         0.0018353 , 0.00194239, 0.99359751, 0.00266747, 0.93044597,
         0.00224771, 0.0030776 , 0.00194221, 0.00194201, 0.00219822,
         0.00160026, 0.0036369 , 0.00219826, 0.00363692, 0.99327594,
         0.00168124, 0.00162628, 0.00229925, 0.98643756, 0.00307718,
         0.00190488, 0.00165313, 0.00298533, 0.00392208, 0.00210552,
         0.00219805, 0.00298561, 0.99316174, 0.00215088, 0.00160023],
        [0.73331004, 0.00307727, 0.99238032, 0.00165311, 0.00298531,
         0.00392205, 0.00210574, 0.00219817, 0.00298594, 0.00170954,
         0.99139601, 0.00160052, 0.99157673, 0.00210574, 0.00307827,
         0.00289894, 0.00289911, 0.92265522, 0.00317498, 0.00307761,
         0.99265867, 0.00194224, 0.00160059, 0.00266738, 0.00219837,
         0.00224767, 0.00307806, 0.00194227, 0.0019423 , 0.00219831,
         0.00160033, 0.00363697, 0.00219824, 0.00363684, 0.00168108,
         0.00168125, 0.00162644, 0.99080211, 0.00339047, 0.00307727,
         0.99238032, 0.00165311, 0.00298531, 0.00392205, 0.00210574,
         0.00219817, 0.00298594, 0.00170954, 0.99139601, 0.00160043]]),
 'test-topic-document-matrix': array([], dtype=float64)}
```

My goal is to at least know the topic for each input data (it'll be great if I can predict new data by the trained model too!)

- I used trial data, so the result is still not that great, but my main objective is to understand how to do topic modelling with OCTIS
- Num topic = 5 (if this helps)
- [OCTIS](https://github.com/MIND-Lab/OCTIS) framework is new, it was published last year! (2021)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Topics in the training data

The topics that the model has found are represented by the top 10 words in that topic.
These can be found in `output['topics']`.
So your first topic would be represented by the words: `['vaksin','sertifikat','aplikasi','pertama','alhamdulillah','pedulilindungi','ada','padahal','terimakasih','nik']`.

To know which topics are found in which document, you should look at `output['topic-document-matrix']`.
The first list in this list represents the distribution of topics in the first document of your training data. Example: the first document mostly consists of topic 2 (because of the value `0.98769081`)

### Prediction on new documents

Unfortunately, this is not possible using OCTIS. OCTIS is exclusively a package for optimizing and comparing topic models. It is possible to [define a test set](https://octis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html#datasets-and-preprocessing), to see how models perform on unseen data. However, OCTIS is not suitable for developing production topic models. If that is your goal, take a look at [gensim](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/). (This is the package that OCTIS uses behind the scenes.)